# Unpack array in function call in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a simple way to unpack an array and pass the values to a (formating) function? I believed something like this could do the job

```
int arr[] = { 8, 30, 45, 1, 1, 21 };
tool.Text.Format("%i:%i:%i  %i-%i-%i", std::for_each(arr, arr + 6, [](int i) {return i; }));  // should be 8:30:45 1-1-21
```

But it does not work

`tool.Text.Format()` hehaves the same way as regular `printf()`

Maybe something from the modern C++ 17 could do the job but I could not really make it work.

Comment: `std::for_each()` simply runs a loop calling a function on each element. It can't be used the way you have shown. There is nothing in C++ that can "unpack" an array into individual parameters the way you want. Maybe if `Format()` were a recursive variadic template function, you might have a chance at implementing a solution. But a simple printf-style function, no way.

Comment: Do you have any questions o comments on the proposed solution below?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look toward this solution. Here, we invert the direction from which we approach it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Printer {
    size_t counter;
public:
    Printer(const size_t &c = 1) : counter(c) {} 
    void operator()(int num) {
        // You can introduce whatever formatting is needed
        counter % 3 ? printf("%i:", num) : printf("%i ", num); // Is not elaborate, but works
        ++counter;
    }
}; 

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 8, 30, 45, 1, 1, 21 };
    std::for_each_n(arr, 6, Printer()); // for_each_n since C++17
    // std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), Printer());
}
```

Note that the `Printer` function object does not prints as in your formatting specifier for the moment, but you can tune it in *(if the approach will be viable).*

Also, the `for_each_n` is accessible since [C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n)

Example:

```
$ g++ foo.cpp -std=c++17 && ./a.out
8:30:45 1:1:21
```

Comment: well, ok, i was just wondering if there is some elegant solution, I am probably not the only one who needs such a thing.  writing custom functor is definitely a way but for instance there is this std::fold_expresion with the operator (.*)  - which is supposed to be "unpacking operator" from what i have understood. but how to use it i don't know..

Comment: @experimental got you!

Comment: i would expect in "modern cpp" doing something like this should be pretty straightforward. what are all these "new features" for when such a common thing as splitting a string or unpacking array values is still not implemented

Comment: @experimental probably all the troubles are due to the fact that VLAs are not a part of this modernity.